# Is sort applied before map in Java Streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to process a `List` using Java streams, but not sure if I can guarantee the `sort` is processed before the `map` method in the following expression:

```
list.stream()
            .sorted((a, b) -> b.getStartTime().compareTo(a.getStartTime()))
            .mapToDouble(e -> {
                        double points = (e.getDuration() / 60);
                        ...                             
                        return points * e.getType().getMultiplier();
                    }
            ).sum();
```

Since I need to perform some calculations based in that specific order.

Comment: Chained stream operations are indeed applied in order.  Is that what you're worried about?

Comment: The entire stream will be sorted and then applied the `mapToDouble` method?

Comment: As sorting requires seeing all input elements before it can output anything, yes.

Comment: What kind of calculations are you doing that would be dependent on the order?

Comment: “perform some calculations based in that specific order” sounds like a semantic error, regardless of when the sorting is done. In your example, there is nothing that could depend on the order anyway.

Comment: There is a niftier way of specifying the sorted condition - use a Comparator. For example instead of `.sorted((a, b) -> b.getStartTime().compareTo(a.getStartTime()))` use: `.sorted(Comparator.comparing((SomeClass a) ->a.getStartTime()).reversed())`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can guarantee that, because the operations in the stream pipeline are applied in the order they are declared (once a terminal operation has been executed).

From [`Stream` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

> To perform a computation, stream operations are composed into a *stream pipeline*. A stream pipeline consists of a source (which might be an array, a collection, a generator function, an I/O channel, etc), zero or more *intermediate operations* (which transform a stream into another stream, such as filter(Predicate)), and a *terminal operation* (which produces a result or side-effect, such as count() or forEach(Consumer)). Streams are lazy; computation on the source data is only performed when the terminal operation is initiated, and source elements are consumed only as needed.

The key word in the above paragraph is **pipeline**, whose [definition in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(software)) starts as follows:

> In software engineering, a pipeline consists of a chain of processing elements (processes, threads, coroutines, functions, etc.), arranged so that the output of each element is the input of the next...

Answer (score 0):

Not only `sorted` will be applied before `map`, but it will obviously traverse the underlying source. `sorted` will get all the elements, put them into an `array` or `ArrayList` (depending if the size is known), sort that and them give one element at a time to the `map` operation.